# How to run a simple main with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I use last Spring Boot, I just neet to run a method and stop program execution after the last instruction, just like à main.

Juste need to run this method :

```
public class Main {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    public void run() throws IOException {
        System.out.println(myService.listAll());
    }
}
```

And the Application class is a simple Spring Boot run

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

So, how to tell to spring boot to run Main.run() with command like java -jar myapp.jar ?

Thank you

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-non-web-application, http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html

Comment: Tomcat isn't trying to run. The exception is a result of the code in com.myapp.ronaldeMigration.api.SchemaRegistryApi.get() making an HTTP call to `localhost:8081` using Apache HTTP Client. Nothing's listening on port 8081 so the HTTP call fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your `Main` implement `CommandLineRunner` and annotate it with `@Component` so that it's found by component scanning:

```
@Component
public class Main implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final MyService myService;

    @Autowired
    Main(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(this.myService.listAll());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it don't works. 2016-01-22 11:57:02.617  INFO 1016 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-01-22 11:57:03.077 ERROR 1016 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
 Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8081 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused  Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Comment: That looks like a bug in your code. Something's trying to connect to localhost:8081 and nothing's listening on that port. It also looks like you're starting Tomcat. Why are you doing that in an application that you want to exit automatically? Tomcat's non-daemon threads will keep the JVM alive unless you explicitly shut it down.